# If I run MongoDB as a service am I also supposed to run the 'mongod' command when I want to access it?

Tags: mongodb, service

I followed this guide ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ )and I run the

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.0
```

,and checked that the service was in fact running.

I thought that having the service running would allow me to just run the

```
mongo
```

shell(or access the db in general), without needing to run

```
mongod
```

on another terminal.

Shouldn't it be the case? Thanks and a Happy Pi day :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have installed mongo as a service then you will also have to install the mongo client then you can use same commands and do the data management